# Can't connect to SQL Azure from EF, but can from SSMS

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, connection-string

We have an Azure SQL server running which we use for our Azure Web App. The Web App can connect without a problem. We're trying to remotely update the database with the latest EF migrations via a C# console application.
However we get the following exception.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

We tried connecting from the same PC with SSMS and we got in without any problems. And yes, before anyone asks we whitelisted the IP in Azure, else we wouldn't even had access via SSMS. We also tried with and without "tcp:" in the connectionstring.

This is the connectionstring we use in the Web and Console Application:

`Server=tcp:{servername}.database.windows.net;Database={dbname};user id = {userid};password = {password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

In SSMS we just use {servername}.database.windows.net and use the credentials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your connection String (without sensitve information) ? Have you check if your IP address and instance name are same with SSMS ?

Comment: I updated my question. Yes, no doubt it's the same IP.

Comment: Is the firewall shutdown during test ? So you use the same connection string with Web App and Consol App. So it's look like your system block the connection for this console.

Comment: Firewall is turned off completely while testing.

Comment: Try to add the following to your connection string: Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True; SSMS may have these options checked by default, while your app is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't been able to solve this issue. We instead chose to go with ReadyRoll, which suits us fine.

Comment: We have switched back to our first approach (console application which updates the DB with code-first migrations) and this time it works like we expected it in the first place. We aren't sure why it works this time around.
For anyone wondering, we switched back from using ReadyRoll because keeping local dev db's in sync with ReadyRoll was a complete nightmare for us. Maybe we were doing something wrong but everything now works as we would like it.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL requires secured connection. You have to add the following to your connection string:

```
Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

Comment: Getting the exact same same exception.

Comment: I;ve checked full connection string in our applications and it looks a bit different than yours, maybe you should try: Data Source=tcp:{servername}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={dbname};User ID={userid};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;